How would I set the Horizontal Alignment for Pivot Table column headers in EPPlus?
I am using EPPlus in a VB.NET application. I am trying the set the Horizontal Alignment of the column headers in my pivot table. However, the column headers are always left aligned.
We have tried the following:
xlPivotsheet.Cells("B6:J6").Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right

This has no effect on the alignment of the cells in the range between B6:J6.
Would anyone know the correct approach to set horizontal alignment with EPPlus?
